# DocuSign API - How to override and skip the recipient authentication screen for specific envelope requests in embedded and remote signing via API?

Tags: docusignapi

In the DocuSign web application, under recipient authentication settings, I have selected the `Disable recipient authentication for this account` setting.

How will this affect my API requests? Say, if I have to enable the recipient authentication just for one signature request, will I be able to do that? Or vice versa. If my administrator has selected the `Any recipient must authenticate on every envelope sent from this account` setting, will I be able to send an envelope via API with a different setting?

I am looking for a way to implement a workflow where DocuSign registered users wouldn't have to login or authenticate when they are signing an envelope within my application, no matter what the 'recipient authentication setting' in the web application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that embedded recipients ("captive" recipients) will not need to authenticate with DocuSign even if the `Any recipient must authenticate on every envelope sent from this account` setting is on. An exception to this would be accounts set up for 21 CFR Part 11 rules.

Best would be to try it out.

I don't know about remote (email) recipients. Best is to try it. Developer accounts are free and you can change the setting via the Demo eSign Admin tool.

### Added

The Demo eSign Admin tool can be reached via the `settings` item in the top navigation of the developer/demo version of the DocuSign application. Or via [admindemo.docusign.com](https://admindemo.docusign.com)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will be trying out. Could you point me to the 'Demo eSign Admin' tool?

Comment: @BambiBundle See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The account settings you are referring to are documented here:
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=muh1583277327950.html&_LANG=enus

What isn't obvious is that these settings are enforced by the DocuSign Web App UI.  Setting `Disable recipient authentication for this account` does not prevent you from doing so via API-created and sent envelopes.  Hope that helps.